# Proof that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is not a semisimple ring?

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

The title says it all ($\mathbb C$ denotes the complex numbers). Perhaps it is not Artinian but I don't know how to prove that either... Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Consider the set of principal ideals generated by powers of $x$. Does it have a minimal element?

Comment: You can preview the changes I made to add TeX to your post by clicking the edit timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ have positive (total) degree. Then
$$
(f)\supsetneq (f^2)\supsetneq (f^3)\supsetneq\dotsb
$$

Alternatively, a commutative semisimple ring is a product of fields, by the Artin-Wedderburn theorem. In particular, an integral domain is semisimple if and only if it is a field.

Comment: Your first statement is what I was looking for. Your second statement though does not hold; take CxC=C^2 which is a commutative semisimple ring that is not a field

Comment: @user128787 Yes, it should have been “product of fields”. I wanted to say “domain”. Fixed.

Comment: Well actually you were not so wrong, if C[x,y] is a product of division rings D1x...xDn then they must be commutative (since C[x,y] is commutative) and also, n must be 1, since C[x,y] is an integral domain, hence C[x,y] would be a field (which is obviously a contradiction). Am I right?

Comment: @user128787 Yes, that's what misled my original statement.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see the difference:

In a semisimple ring, every right ideal is generated by an idempotent. In fact, every element is the product of an idempotent and unit.

On the other hand, a domain like $\mathbb C[x,y]$ only has two idempotents: $\{0,1\}$.